# LM2596 minimum input voltage question

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to feed the LM2596 (DC to DC) booster a 9V battery. Now, I see that it has a minimum voltage required of 3V. My question is this:

What happens when my 9V battery drops below 3V? Would that damage the booster, or it would just stop working? Would a minimum voltage drop increase the overall temperature on the LM2596?

Comment: Your 9V battery will run out of material ***long*** before it hits 3V.

Comment: The simple answer is you should not discharge a 9V battery at 3V. It is not good for the battery if it is rechargeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM2596 has current limit and thermal shutdown protection that should prevent damage to the chip, even if it were to overheat due to high currents at the reduced input voltage.

In practice I would guess that a normal 9V alkaline battery with reasonable output current will probably not be able to get it to overheat at all.

Comment: Thanks, Spehro, so once the minimum input is reached the only outcome would be loosing all output voltage, correct ?

Comment: That's my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

It should not damage the booster itself, but you need to experiment to get a better idea.

There are many other things which may affect you: internal resistance of the discharging battery, others components (you don't feed a bare LM2596, but the whole module with diode, inductor, capacitors, etc) and the type of your actual load (constant current, power spikes, etc).